# Blur Function Not working In Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with jQuery `Blur` Function

I code it like this:

```
<head>
<script src="_js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#l').blur(function(){
        if($(this).val()=='')
            alert('Invalid');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
```

I am using this to identify if the input field is empty or not. If I run this code then if I leave it empty and click somewhere else, the `Blur` function is not called and no alert is generated

I am using Firefox 10.1 to run the code

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="Login.php" id="Log">
<select id="Login" name="Type">
<option value="Sel" selected="selected">Select Login type</option>
<option value="Student">Student</option>
<option value="Faculity">Faculity</option>
</select>
<div id="type">
<p id="Ch">Group Id: &nbsp;<input id="l" name="log" type="text"/></p>
<p id="Pass">Password: &nbsp; <input id="p" name="Pass" type="password" /></p>
<input id="Cond" type="Text" />
<input type="submit" value="Login"  />
</div>
<p id="Invalid" style="padding-top:.75em; color:#FF0000;">Login Field Empty </p>
</form>
```

The content of code changes through selection and code is this
The Group id And Password Are Hidden At The Beginning And Changes When The Option Is Selected In Below Code

```
$('#Login').change(function() {
if($(this).val()=='Sel')
$('#type').hide();
else if($(this).val()=='Student')
{
    $('#Ch').html('<p id="Ch">Group Id: &nbsp; &nbsp;<input id="l" name=" log" type="text" /></p>')
    $('#type').show(10);
}
else
{
$('#Ch').html('<p id="Ch">Faculity Id: &nbsp;<input id="l" name="log" type="text" /></p>')
$('#type').show(10);
}
```

});

I Think It Is Causing Problem Kindly Check And Tell Me What's It Alternative If It Causes Some Problem Or I Am Doing It Wrong??

Comment: And could you please stop using initial caps for every word - it is very hard to read and not cool at all. I fixed it for you but it was a lot of work

Answer (score 6):

`$('#input')` the # is for ID selector, try the `$('input')` tag name selector.

Comment: I have Input Field As <input id="Input" type=text />

Comment: did you try `$('#Input')` yet?

Comment: and where are you putting the function call? if you put the function before the `<input id="Input" type=text />` it WON'T work because the javascript finds no matches for your given selector. Either put it right before `</body>` or wrap it inside a `$(document).ready(function(){<your function here>});`.

Comment: My Function Is in Head Tag With document.ready(function ()) But It Still don't Works I Don't Know What's The Matter

Comment: Do you have more than 1 input with `id="Input"`? If so, JQuery will only apply your code to the first match found. More than 1 element with same id is considered invalid HTML. You should use classes if you want to select more than 1 element. Try adding `class="input"` to all your inputs then just call `$('.input')`.

Comment: `$('#l')` will only add your `.blur()` event to the first element with `id="l"`. If you want to add the event to all your `input`s, just use `$('input')`

Comment: I am only concerned with one id="l" but it still don't call blur function when i move somewhere else

Comment: if you want to apply to all inputs, use `$('input')`. If you want to apply only to that field, your code is working perfectly fine. Make sure to ctrl+F5 your browser and that your field is actually empty when it loses focus (firefox keeps fields' value even when you refresh the page, so check if there isn't any white space).

Comment: I think it could be but in reality its not working what can i do ??

Comment: First look if there isn't any other element with that same ID in your html. Then put an alert inside the `.ready()` to make sure that your jquery file is loading and the `.ready()` is firing. If it fires, open firefox's Web Console (Ctrl+Shift+K) and check if there are any errors in your javascript when the page loads or when your input loses focus.

Comment: I made a [jsfeedle](http://jsfiddle.net/GHFRe/) with your code, it's running perfectly fine for what you asked. Make sure you have your page saved in the same directory as the `_js` folder which you're referencing at  `_js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js`. Or maybe give it a try with the google-hosted version? `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I Have Edited The Code Kindly Look And Tell Is This The Problem

Comment: There were 2 mistakes on your code: 1st, you were creating duplicate IDs inside the elements. 2nd, if you want to change only the textifeld's label, you don't have to replace the whole paragraph. Just wrap it inside a span and change its html. I got your code running, check if this is what you wanted: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/D5rBv/)

Answer (score 1):

Unless your input has an ID of "input", you should be referencing your input as `$('input')`. This will create a jQuery object with all the elements of type "input".

Comment: I have Input Field As <input id="Input" type=text />

Answer (score 0):

In your post, you have this chunk of JavaScript code:

```
$('#Login').change(function() {
if($(this).val()=='Sel')
$('#type').hide();
else if($(this).val()=='Student')
{
    $('#Ch').html('<p id="Ch">Group Id: &nbsp; &nbsp;<input id="l" name=" log" type="text" /></p>')
    $('#type').show(10);
}
else
{
$('#Ch').html('<p id="Ch">Faculity Id: &nbsp;<input id="l" name="log" type="text" /></p>')
$('#type').show(10);
}
```

Can I ask where this code is placed within the page?  There may be an issue with the order of execution.